# Build a column with previous month information in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have this example of df

I do some transformations on it and I need to get my mark value from the previous month in a new column to make comparisons. that column should have the maximum value of the column 'mark' according to the different values in 'id' column.

here is an example of the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['202301','202301','202301','202301','202302','202302','202302','202302','202303','202303','202303','202304','202304'], 
            'mark': [1,1,2,3,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1
],
                  'id':[20,20,21,21,20,20,21,21,20,20,21,20,21
]})
```

and here is the desired output

```
date    mark    id  mark_previous
202301  1   20  0
202301  1   20  0
202301  2   21  0
202301  3   21  0
202302  1   20  1
202302  1   20  1
202302  1   21  3
202302  1   21  3
202303  1   20  1
202303  3   20  1
202303  1   21  1
202304  1   20  3
202304  1   21  1
```

What do you recommend to obtain that column?

Best regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
g = df.groupby(['date', 'id'])
df['mark_previous'] = g.tail(1).groupby('id')['mark'].shift()
df['mark_previous'] = g['mark_previous'].transform('max').fillna(0).astype('int')
```

df :

```
    date    mark    id  mark_previous
0   202301  1       20  0
1   202301  1       20  0
2   202301  2       21  0
3   202301  3       21  0
4   202302  1       20  1
5   202302  1       20  1
6   202302  1       21  3
7   202302  1       21  3
8   202303  1       20  1
9   202303  3       20  1
10  202303  1       21  1
11  202304  1       20  3
12  202304  1       21  1
```

---

**Intermediate**

```
g.tail(1).groupby('id')['mark'].shift()
```

:

```
1       NaN
3       NaN
5    1.0000
7    3.0000
9    1.0000
10   1.0000
11   3.0000
12   1.0000
Name: mark, dtype: float64
```